# AvalonEdit :: Ctrl + I KeyBinding Doesn't Work

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, key-bindings, avalonedit

I am using AvalonEdit to (surprise) create a text editor.  I have added KeyBindings to the declaration:

```
<ae:TextEditor x:Name="TextEditor" ... >
   <ae:TextEditor.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Command="ToggleBold" Key="B" Modifiers="Control"/>
      <KeyBinding Command="ToggleItalic" Key="I" Modifiers ="Control"/>
      <!-- other bindings -->
   </ae:TextEditor.InputBindings>
</ae:TextEditor>
```

I have about twenty-ish buttons associated with the typical Commands and they're all working, including `EditingCommands.ToggleItalic`.  I have KeyBindings associated with the commands and they all work as expected *with the sole exception of* **`Ctrl+I`**.  I cannot get the Ctrl+I keybinding combination to work with *any* Command (tried using it with ToggleBold, for instance).

To be clear:

1. The `KeyBinding` for `ToggleItalic` works if I bind to something that *isn't* `Ctrl+I` - `Ctrl+Shift+I`, for example, works perfectly.
2. The `Ctrl+I` combination doesn't seem to work for *any* KeyBinding.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?  I don't want to deviate from the default KeyBindings - `Ctrl+I` for ToggleItalics is pretty ingrained for those of us that are fond of our keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ctrl+I` KeyGesture in the AvalonEdit control is already associated to the `IndentSelection` AvalonEditCommand (it is a RoutedCommand, so it can have one or more InputGestures).

If you take a look to the `AvalonEditCommands` class, you will find this code:

```
public static readonly RoutedCommand IndentSelection = new RoutedCommand( 
    "IndentSelection", typeof(TextEditor), 
    new InputGestureCollection { 
        new KeyGesture(Key.I, ModifierKeys.Control) 
});
```

So you have to remove the IndentSelection CommandBinding (in the `EditingCommandHandler` class) in order to use the `Ctrl+I` KeyGesture for another command.

**EDIT**
I was thinking you can try to solve your problem by clearing the `InputGestureCollection` of the IndentSelection command in your `Application.OnStartup` method:

```
protected virtual void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AvalonEditCommands.IndentSelection.InputGestures.Clear();
    /* If you want now you can add a new inputgesture */
    /* The rest of your code... */
}
```

I did not test this solution, but I suppose it can work.

Comment: How can I access that class?  I can't find an instance of it on any of the TextEditor properties...  Where are they hiding it?

Comment: @ScottSEA, I edited my answer with an alternative (and simplier) solution.